# Finding the sum of an alternating series by converting it to a series where are the terms are positive

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Problem:

Find the sum of the following series:
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} +  \ldots $$

Answer:

Observe that this is a alternating series with $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Since all the terms are getting smaller and
the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ the series converges. Let $S$ be the sum we seek.
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^i \\
S &= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} \right)
  + \left( \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{32} \right) + \ldots \\
S &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{32}  + \ldots 
\end{align*}
This is a geomertric series. We have:
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{1}{2} \\
r &= \frac{1}{4} \\
S &= \frac{a}{1 - r} = \frac{  \frac{1}{2} }{ 1 - \frac{1}{4} } \\
S &= \frac{  \frac{1}{2} }{ \frac{3}{4} } \\
S &= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

Using Python, I have estimated the sum of the series to be: $0.6665039$. Do I have it right now?

The original series was geometric so I could have simple applied the formula for a geometric series. However, I did not think of it until I completed the problem. I am hoping that somebody can confirm that the method I used in this problem is right (assuming it is right).

Comment: Your approach with the geometric series looks fine to me.

Comment: I think this is okay, but it might worth noting that you cannot regroup/rearrange the terms as you have unless the series is absolutely convergent. (Luckily the geometric series is.) At least I'm pretty sure that's a thing being assumed here.

Comment: To avoid regrouping the terms, you can say that $$ \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^i=\frac{1}{1+1/2}=\frac{2}{3} $$ Be careful, your sum starts at $i=0$ and there is an error of sign.